# Can I replace dataLayer.push() with gtag()?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

While trying to implement and understand the use of Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics I was wondering why there is talk about `dataLayer.push()` in [some places](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/datalayer) while `gtag()` is used for similar operations in [other places](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/events). They seems to be serving the same purpose even though the result is not exactly the same.

`gtag()` is defined as:

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
```

If I try the code I get a wrapping Arguments-object when using gtag. So I understand that there is a difference, but does this matter and should they be used for different purposes?

```
> dataLayer = []
> dataLayer.push({'event','login'})
[{'event','login'}]
> dataLayer = []
> gtag({'event','login'})
[Arguments({'event','login'})]
```

When should either one of them be used or could I resolve to only using one of them?

Comment: Where did you find the source code of gtag() and dataLayer.push()?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, there is no difference. `gtag()` is just a wrapper JS function around `dataLayer.push()`. However, `gtag` is preferable.

The reason for using `gtag` is to avoid any action that might pollute or change data inside `dataLayer` object by accident, which might affect analytic data.

Technically, they're the same, and you can use either ways.

Personally, when tagging events, I usually create my own function:

```
// definition
function gevent(name, data) { 
    gtag('event', name, data);
}

// sample
gevent('level_up', { userId: 123, prevLevel: 12, currLevel: 13 });
gevent('logout', { userId: 123 });
```

Comment: I do the same but I do not know how come the info I send using dataLayer.push is not actually sent to Google Analytics 4, and I can only see the events and dimensions created by dataLayer.push in `tagassistant` and not in `analytics.google`. any idea?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami for events and dimensions that are not default by GA4, you need to create them, Custom Events, Custom Dimensions. Data will only be available when custom events and dimensions are registered properly and there are events sent in last 24 hours